# setImageUri leaves the ImageView blank

Tags: android, imageview, uri

I use BSImagePicker library in my application to let the user pick or take an image. The library has the following method (also my code):

```
    @Override
    public void onSingleImageSelected(Uri uri) {
        selectedImagePath = uri;
        imageSelected = true;
        imageViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageView.setImageURI(uri);
        imageView.invalidate();
    }
```

My problem is that the ImageView remains empty after the user chooses (or takes) an image. The URI is correct, because I also use it to upload the image to the cloud and it works fine there. The callback is working correctly because the imageViewContainer appears at the right time.

I also tried setImageBitmap with BitmapFactory and setImageDrawable, but the ImageView just stays blank. What am I doing wrong?

My corresponding xml:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_container"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/image_container"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

EDIT: The URI passed to the function: `file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180829_211617.jpg`

Comment: Did you try debugging and see what URI is being passed to imageView?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question.

Comment: No, that works.

Comment: Could you please try to call imageView.setImageDrawable(null); before imageView.setImageURI(uri);

Comment: try after removing         imageView.invalidate();

Comment: Do you have permission to access file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180829_211617.jpg?

Comment: If I open the input stream of the uri the first read returns 255(int), the resolver.getType(uri) returns null.
Setting the image to null before actually setting it doesn't seem to do anything just like removing the invalidate call.
And yes, I have permission to read the file.

Comment: I use the exact same uri later in the activity to upload the image to the cloud and that works perfectly so I don't think this is a problem with the file or the URI.

Comment: How do I read the stream as hex?

Comment: I have `ff d8 ff e1 2f 39 45 78 69 66`. And yes, BitmapFactory does produce a non-null bitmap.

Comment: As I mentioned it in the post I tried that already but it didn't work.

Comment: In debug mode I can view the bitmap and it is in fact not null. But still the imageView remains blank when I set the bitmap to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I still don't know what the problem actually was, but I made it work like this:

```
@Override
public void onSingleImageSelected(Uri uri) {
    selectedImagePath = uri;
    imageSelected = true;
    imageViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    try {
        Bitmap image = scaleBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        showAlertFlashBar("Image not found.");
    }
}
```

, where scaleBitmap just scaled the bitmap to the desired dimensions.